# Spring mvc:resources is overridden by @RequestMapping?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a @RequestMapping on one of my controllers:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/{folder}/{subFolder}/{page}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

In my xml file i defined a resource:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/_resources/**" location="/_resources/" />
```

When i access the following resource it is handled by ResourceHttpRequestHandler:

```
http://www.example.com/_resources/logo.png
```

But when i access:

```
http://www.example.com/_resources/extcss/bootstrap.css
```

it is handled by the @RequestMapping not by the ResourceHttpRequestHandler, causeing a MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException with nested NumberFormatException cause "bootstrap" isn't a number.

I never had this problem with other projects.

How can i change my mvc:resources mapping to include subdirectories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that @RequestMapping overrides the resource mapping by default.

To solve this i changed the {page} path variable to a more strict version using regex: {page:[0-9]+}.

Now both urls work nicely, until ofcourse you start using resources which only contain numbers in the filename, but that doesn't often happen.